# Installation of Windows with Unetbootin won't finish

Tags: windows, boot, windows-installation, unetbootin

Loaded an ISO with Win Server 2008 R2 onto a flash drive using Unetbootin. Booted just fine, went through most of the install process, server reboots just before "completing installation" then after rebooting goes back to the first screen. Installation doesn't ever complete.

Attempting to boot into hard drive results in blue screens.

Any ideas?

My only other option is PXE booting since this server has no disk drive.

This is the blue screen I receive:

> A problem has been detected and windows has been shut down to prevent
>   damage to your computer.
>
> If this is the first time you've seen this Stop error screen, restart
>   your computer. If this screen appears again, follow these steps:
>
> Check to be sure you have adequate disk space. If a driver is
>   identified in the stop message, disable the driver or check with the
>   manufacturer for driver updates. Try changing video adapters.
>
> Check with your hardware vendor for any BIOS udpates. Disable BIOS
>   memory options such as caching or shadowing. If you need to use Safe
>   Mode to remove or disable components, restart your computer, press F8
>   to select Advance Startup Options, and then select Safe Mode.
>
> Technical information:
>
> *** STOP: 0x0000001E (0x0000000000000, etc, etc)

UPDATE (9/18/2014): Thank you Pat for your suggestion to use "Serva". It worked beautifully.

Comment: Try taking the flash drive out (or change your boot order) before it finishes rebooting, doe sit still "go back to the first screen"?  Which blue screen error code is presented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My only other option is PXE booting since this server has no disk drive

You can PXE install your OS with Microsoft WDS (runs as a server service) or for a much simpler approach you can give [Serva](http://vercot.com/~serva/an/WindowsPXE1.html) a try (I'm related to Serva development) and you'll get your OS net installed in no time.

Answer (score 0):

Tried Serva but got the following error:

[09/17 15:30:38.823] BINL Inf: Preparation/Maintenance procedures "Start" **
[09/17 15:30:38.853] BINL Inf: Preparation/Maintenance procedures "End" **
[09/17 15:35:03.672] PDHCP Inf: Rcvd DHCPDISCOVER from IP 0.0.0.0, MAC Inventec/00:A0:D1:EB:79:28
[09/17 15:35:03.672] PDHCP Inf: Sending DHCPOFFER
[09/17 15:35:03.672] PDHCP Inf: Broadcasting through local interface [10.0.0.36]
[09/17 15:35:03.672] PDHCP Inf: Broadcasting through local interface [192.168.1.50]
[09/17 15:35:05.632] PDHCP Inf: Rcvd DHCPREQUEST from IP 0.0.0.0, MAC Inventec/00:A0:D1:EB:79:28
[09/17 15:35:05.632] PDHCP Inf: Rcvd DHCPREQUEST from IP 10.0.0.181, MAC Inventec/00:A0:D1:EB:79:28
[09/17 15:35:05.632] PDHCP Inf: Sending DHCPACK, TFTP [10.0.0.36]  bootfile [pxeserva.0]
[09/17 15:35:05.632] TFTP Inf: Read file . Mode octet
[09/17 15:35:05.682] TFTP Err: Peer returns ERROR  -> aborting transfer
[09/17 15:35:05.682] TFTP Inf: Read file . Mode octet
[09/17 15:35:06.782] TFTP Err: timeout waiting for ack blk 16#1 #1
[09/17 15:35:08.782] TFTP Err: timeout waiting for ack blk 16#1 #1
[09/17 15:35:11.786] TFTP Err: timeout waiting for ack blk 16#1 #1
[09/17 15:35:14.786] TFTP Err: timeout waiting for ack blk 16#1 #1
[09/17 15:35:17.786] TFTP Err: timeout waiting for ack blk 16#1 #1
[09/17 15:35:20.787] TFTP Err: timeout waiting for ack blk 16#1 #1
[09/17 15:35:20.787] TFTP Err: TIMEOUT & abort waiting for Ack block #1

UPDATE (9/18/2014): Never had to mess with MTU settings before but Pat's suggestion worked.

Comment: read Serva troubleshooting; your problem is either a Firewall problem or MTU different than 1500 on Serva's PC. You should also check your client's firmware is updated.